# How can I move the close button to the top-right corner of the box in slimbox (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, plugins

I want to have my button in the top-right corner, I tried position: absolute, but I think the position of the box is not relative so I can't use top: 0;.

Any suggestions?

```
CSS:

/* SLIMBOX */

#lbOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#lbCenter, #lbBottomContainer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.lbLoading {
    background: #fff url(slimbox2/loading.gif) no-repeat center;
}

#lbImage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#lbPrevLink, #lbNextLink {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    outline: none;
}

#lbPrevLink {
    left: 0;
}

#lbPrevLink:hover {
    background: transparent url(slimbox2/prevlabel.gif) no-repeat 0 15%;
}

#lbNextLink {
    right: 0;
}

#lbNextLink:hover {
    background: transparent url(slimbox2/nextlabel.gif) no-repeat 100% 15%;
}

#lbBottom {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align: left;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    border-top-style: none;
}

#lbCloseLink {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 31px;
    height: 32px;
    background: transparent url(slimbox2/closelabel.gif) no-repeat center;
    margin: 5px 0;
    outline: none;
}
#lbCloseLink:hover {
    background: transparent url(slimbox2/closelabel_hover.gif) no-repeat center;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

#lbCaption, #lbNumber {
    margin-right: 71px;
}

#lbCaption {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The button `#lbCloseLink` is inside of `#lbBottomContainer`, which is positioned absolutely.

You can try `margin-top: -Npx` on the button, but for this to work you have to know the height of your content and remove `overflow: hidden` on `#lbBottomContainer`.
The other solution might be to patch Slimbox and put the button into `#lbCenter`.

Answer (score 0):

I edited slimbox.js (first extend the script with : http://jsbeautifier.org/ ), and slimbox.css`

1) EDIT slimbox.js

```
I.setStyles({
                width: N,
                top: O, /* modified for TOP POSITION; original was O+t */
                marginLeft: -N / 2,
                visibility: "hidden",
                display: ""
            });


b.setStyles({
            overflow:"visible", /* new line inserted for visibility TOP POSITION */
                top: Math.max(0, z - (t / 2)),
                width: N,
                height: t,
                marginLeft: -N / 2,
                display: ""
            });
```

2) EDIT slimbox.css

```
#lbBottom {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Geneva, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #666;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    text-align: left;
    border-right: 10px solid #fff; /* modified: line inserted for TOP POSITION */
    border-left: 10px solid #fff;  /* modified: line inserted for TOP POSITION */
}

#lbCloseLink {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 66px;
    height: 22px;
    background: transparent url(closelabel.gif) no-repeat center;
    margin:0 0 0 0; /* modified for TOP POSITION */
    outline: none;
}

#lbCaption, #lbNumber {
    margin-right: 71px;
    margin-top:7px; /* line inserted for TOP POSITION */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to version 2.05
you need to insert lbCloseLink into the lbCenter div; this can be approached by cutting the

```
w('<a id="lbCloseLink" href="#" />').click(C)[0],
```

and appending it to unnamed div with relative position

```
g=w('<div id="lbImage" rel=""/>').appendTo(a).append(p=w('<div style="position: relative;" />').append([w('<a id="lbCloseLink" href="#" />').click(C)[0],I=w('<a id="lbPrevLink" href="#" />').click(B)[0],d=w('<a id="lbNextLink" href="#" />').click(e)[0]])[0])[0];c=w('<div id="lbBottom" />').appendTo(G).append([A=w('<div id="lbCaption" />')[0],K=w('<div id="lbNumber" />')[0],w('<div style="clear: both;" />')[0]])[0];
```

after that, you need to customize slimbox2.css, make the lbCloselink position absolute and z-index higher than 1 and also you may delete float: right; because since it has absolute position, float has no effect

```
#lbCloseLink {
position: absolute;
right:0px;
z-index: 2;
display: block;
width: %yourwidth%;
height: %yourheight%;
background: transparent url(closelabel.gif) no-repeat center;
outline: none;}
```